# What is the context of em?

Tags: html, css, font-size

In this example:

**THE CSS**

```
h1 { font-size: 2em; }
.smaller { font-size: 0.5em; }
```

**THE HTML**

```
<h1>Hi, I am a <span class="smaller">toad</span></h1>
```

Will the word "toad" be 0.5 times 16px (the browser's standard font-size) or will it be 0.5 times 2em (the font-size of the h1)?

Comment: looking at the "computed style" tab in your friendly dom inspector will help you figuring out these calculations

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's equal to the **computed** value of the ‘font-size’ property of the element on which it is used. Inheritance runs down the document tree.

To answer your question, it would be 0.5 times the 2em, which in turn would be 2 times whatever the h1's parent's computed font-size is. *phew*.

It's also important to note that if you use `em` on other CSS properties, for example, `width` or `height`, the result will be calculated from the computed `font-size` of whatever element you apply the `width` or `height` to, etc...

The following article describes the use and context of the `em` unit rather well in my opinion, along with some other reading material and resources... `rem` units may interest you somewhat also.

1. http://www.impressivewebs.com/understanding-em-units-css/
2. http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem
3. http://caniuse.com/rem

You may also like to check out this fiddle to see how it acts a little clearer:

http://jsfiddle.net/HpJjt/3/

Comment: It's only the computed 'font-size' property of the element on which it is used if it's used with some other property. If it's used on 'font-size' itself then it references the *parent's* computed font size for its own computation.

Comment: Realistically, it's not necessarily the parent, it's just whatever it inherits, for example, if the body had it's `font-size` set to `16px`, and you nested 5 divs within each other and on the last one had the font-size set to `2em`, its resulting computed `font-size` would be `32px`.

Comment: Well, yeah. Either way it's the same since as you said inheritance runs down the doctree from parent to child.

Answer (score 3):

The [`em` unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-length) denotes the font size of the element, except when used in the value of the `font-size` property, where it denotes the font size of the parent element. In this sense, in the case presented, the context is the parent element.

In the case presented, the font size of the word “toad” is thus equal to the font size of the parent of the `h1`. No specific value for it can be inferred for it from the data given.

When font sizes is computed, the font size of the parent of `h1` has been computed when this construct will be dealt with; let’s call it *s*. First the font size of `h1` is computed, multiplying *s* (the font size of the parent) by 2. Then the font size of the `span` element is computed, multiplying its parent’s font size by 0.5, yielding *s*. Theoretically, rounding errors could cause a minimal deviation in such processes, but multiplication by 2 and 0.5 can be assumed to be exact in computers.

Answer (score 1):

It would be .5 times the 2em of the h1 element in context.

To force it to be relative to the 16px, you would have to set the parent of h1 to font-size 16px first.

.wrapper{font-size:16px;}
h1 { font-size: 2em; }
.smaller { font-size: 0.5em; }

```
<div class="wrapper"><h1>Hi, I am a <span class="smaller">toad</span></h1></div>
```

SO in this case,

- wrapper has a font-size of 16px
- h1 has a font-size of 2em of 16px
- span.smaller has a font-size of 1em (of .wrapper inherited from h1 (.5em of 2em)) of 16px

Note that em is a relative measure from the context which is nominally based on the M characters height in the current font.  For all intents then h1 has a 32px size and span.smaller has a 16px size.

Comment: or you could use `rem` units instead of `em` to be relative to the browser base `font-size` (with all the issues of browser support of course)

Comment: @Luca - yea, the support issue is why css "reset" exists and are used often so that the "starting point" is a more consistently predicted value.

Comment: yeah that's definitely a general valid point, I was mostly referring to this: http://caniuse.com/rem (as usual IE gets in the way!)

Comment: @Luca - yes, support for rem is not "yet" universal and as always your use of a "reset" css to some base will/should somewhat depend on your usage - pure CSS styling vs code manipulation vs what "most" of your page desire is (computationally, 10px=1em is much easier on the brain than 16px=1em but it is not as common to actually want your page to display 10px fonts so setting to 10px base (approx 62.5% of 16px) means you have to set lots of stuff to 1.2em from that 10px/1em to obtain say a 12px font - and we will leave the pica/point thing to another day :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the parent element pixel size. If your parent element pixel size is 16px

`.5em` will equal to half of your base pixel so it will be `8px` and `2em` for h1 will equal to `32px`.

It all depends on how you have set up the parent element pixel size in your CSS.

[**http://pxtoem.com/**](http://pxtoem.com/)

Comment: No. It is based on the computed font size of the parent element, not the body font size.

Comment: @Quentin: I too mean parent size. I didn't say body. Will edit base to parent.

Comment: But in this case the parents font-size in pixels, isn't it?

Comment: @RascalCapac thats just a reference. It will be always in pixels